# Populate Form on new page from GridView Select

Tags: c#, forms, datagrid, populate

I have my gridview populated, and I'd like to populate a form with gridview values along with values that are tied to that record but are not on the gridview. I'll post my code I have so far. I know how to populate textboxes in the same form, but I need to launch a new form with these values.

**Data Layer**

```
class DALCustomers
{
    DALConnection SBAConnection;

    public DALCustomers()
    {
        SBAConnection = new DALConnection();
    }

    DataSet GetCustomersDataset = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand Customers = new SqlCommand();
    Customers.CommandText = "GetCustomers";
    Customers.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    Customers.Connection = SBAConnection.GetConnection();

    SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Customers);
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(GetCustomersDataset);
    return GetCustomersDataset;
}
```

**BusinessLayer**

```
class Customer
{
    public DataSet GrabCustDataset()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = new DALCustomers().GetCustomers();
        return ds;
    }
}
```

**UI Layer**

```
namespace Customer_Database
{
    public partial class frmCustomers : Form
    {
        public frmCustomers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PopulateCustomerGrid(DataSet CustGrid)
        {
            dgCustomers.DataSource = null;
            dgCustomers.DataSource = CustGrid.Tables[0];
        }

        private void frmCustomers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new Customer().GrabCustDataset();
            PopulateCustomerGrid(ds);

        }

        private void dgCustomers_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            frmCustDetails frmCustDetails = new frmCustDetails();
            frmCustDetails.Show();

            // will fill TB for selected row
            //foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgCustomers.SelectedRows)
            //{
            //    txtTest.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            //}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the primary key of the selected row to the new form. Use the PK to pull the record from the Database and populate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to go from a main page with a list of data to a details page with data (perhaps expanded) for a selected row from that GridView.

To do that, you can set up your details page to read the data's key (id) from QueryString, then query your DAL for the full details and display them.

On your main page, you'd hook up to the GridView's `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, get the DataKey from the event args, then do a `Response.Redirect` to your details page, passing in the row ID in the QueryString.

To get the data from the GridView, make sure in the ASPX you have set GridView's DataKeyNames property to the key of your Customer class.

Then handle the OnSelectedIndexChanged event, and in the code-behind you'll have access to your GridView's SelectedIndex.  You can use that to get into the DataKeys with the following code:

```
var dataKey = GridView.DataKeys[GridView.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
```

You would then call

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("Details.aspx?CustomerId={0}", dataKey));
```

Comment: yea thats the main point, if you can point me in the right direction to just populate the form from gridview values only that would be great  :). this is a strictly c# program as well if that helps

Comment: Updated my answer with some snippets.